# sort behavior when using numerical option: "sort -k2,2 -nk6,6 foo" vs "sort -k2,2 -k6,6n foo"

Tags: sort

The two examples in the title produce very different results. The first (`sort -k2,2 -nk6,6 foo`) brings back the following results:

```
153759 townhome 900 2 1 79000
876543 townhome 745 2 1 79000
222999 townhome 850 2 2 83333
759153 condo 850 2 1.5 85000
453215 townhome 1000 3 1.5 86000
646484 condo 890 3 1 93333
444555 condo 930 2 1 99999
```

etc.

The second (`sort -k2,2 -k6,6n foo`) brings back:

```
759153 condo 850 2 1.5 85000
646484 condo 890 3 1 93333
444555 condo 930 2 1 99999
777894 condo 790 3 1 101000
221155 condo 1030 3 1 109500
248624 duplex 1250 3 1 120000
987654 duplex 1100 3 1.5 140000
```

These are the correct results I'm looking for.

What causes the difference?

Comment: the first one sorts both numerically, the second only sorts the second numerically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [mikeserv said](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/246262/sort-behavior-when-using-numerical-option-sort-k2-2-nk6-6-foo-vs-sort-k2#comment423083_246262), but with more words:

Using the 'global' `-n` numeric sort option changes sort's global behavior to use numeric sorting for all the keys ([reference](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/sort.c#n4368)) by setting gkey.numeric and then later [setting every key's](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/sort.c#n4624) sort option to the globally-set numeric-sort option. This causes the sorting on field 2 to fail, so it falls through to sorting (numerically) on field 6.

Setting the `n` [ordering option](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/sort-invocation.html) inside the `-k` option only affects sorting on that field, so it can then sort on field 2 until that's not unique, then fall through to numerically sorting on field 6.

Because I could not find 'duplex' lines in your first sort example, I uniquely combined all of the sample lines to create a new sample input file:

```
153759 townhome 900 2 1 79000
221155 condo 1030 3 1 109500
222999 townhome 850 2 2 83333
248624 duplex 1250 3 1 120000
444555 condo 930 2 1 99999
453215 townhome 1000 3 1.5 86000
646484 condo 890 3 1 93333
759153 condo 850 2 1.5 85000
777894 condo 790 3 1 101000
876543 townhome 745 2 1 79000
987654 duplex 1100 3 1.5 140000
```

...against which we can demonstrate sort's behavior with the `--debug` flag; notice the "no match" warnings and the underscores on the 6th field, indicating the portion of the line that sort used for sorting:

```
$ sort -k2,2 -nk6,6 --debug < input
sort: using ‘en_US.UTF-8’ sorting rules
153759 townhome 900 2 1 79000
       ^ no match for key
                        _____
_____________________________
876543 townhome 745 2 1 79000
       ^ no match for key
                        _____
_____________________________
222999 townhome 850 2 2 83333
       ^ no match for key
                        _____
_____________________________
759153 condo 850 2 1.5 85000
       ^ no match for key
                       _____
____________________________
453215 townhome 1000 3 1.5 86000
       ^ no match for key
                           _____
________________________________
646484 condo 890 3 1 93333
       ^ no match for key
                     _____
__________________________
444555 condo 930 2 1 99999
       ^ no match for key
                     _____
__________________________
777894 condo 790 3 1 101000
       ^ no match for key
                     ______
___________________________
221155 condo 1030 3 1 109500
       ^ no match for key
                      ______
____________________________
248624 duplex 1250 3 1 120000
       ^ no match for key
                       ______
_____________________________
987654 duplex 1100 3 1.5 140000
       ^ no match for key
                         ______
_______________________________
```

vs:

```
$ sort -k2,2 -k6,6n --debug < input
sort: using ‘en_US.UTF-8’ sorting rules
sort: leading blanks are significant in key 1; consider also specifying 'b'
759153 condo 850 2 1.5 85000
      ______
                       _____
____________________________
646484 condo 890 3 1 93333
      ______
                     _____
__________________________
444555 condo 930 2 1 99999
      ______
                     _____
__________________________
777894 condo 790 3 1 101000
      ______
                     ______
___________________________
221155 condo 1030 3 1 109500
      ______
                      ______
____________________________
248624 duplex 1250 3 1 120000
      _______
                       ______
_____________________________
987654 duplex 1100 3 1.5 140000
      _______
                         ______
_______________________________
153759 townhome 900 2 1 79000
      _________
                        _____
_____________________________
876543 townhome 745 2 1 79000
      _________
                        _____
_____________________________
222999 townhome 850 2 2 83333
      _________
                        _____
_____________________________
453215 townhome 1000 3 1.5 86000
      _________
                           _____
________________________________
```