# sorting a file on coulumn 1 then column 2 then column3

Tags: sort

I want to sort my file shown below

```
chr17   84938   85187   1   100 1
chr12   86723   87265   2   100 1
chr12   87368   87556   11  100 1
chr12   87704   87880   10  100 1
chr12   88018   88256   3   75  1
chr12   88018   88569   1   25  1
chr17   88171   69528   1   100 2
chr12   88393   88569   6   100 1
chr12   88750   88859   3   100 1
chr12   88772   88859   3   100 1
chr12   89019   89674   7   100 1
chr12   89828   90586   1   100 1
chr12   90656   90795   3   100 1
chr17   93459   92763   1   100 2
chr17   96901   69528   4   100 2
chr17   100273  99697   1   100 2
chr16   101557  97558   13  100 2
chr16   103475  101646  8   100 2
chr16   104059  105458  18  100 1
chr16   105550  105776  19  100 1
chr16   105883  106538  17  100 1
chr16   106614  107085  20  100 1
chr18   107887  109384  1   100 1
chr16   108971  108759  2   100 2
```

First I want to sort on column1 then column 2 and then column 3 (all ascending order)

I did that in excel and got this result

```
chr12   86723   87265   2   100 1
chr12   87368   87556   11  100 1
chr12   87704   87880   10  100 1
chr12   88018   88256   3   75  1
chr12   88018   88569   1   25  1
chr12   88393   88569   6   100 1
chr12   88750   88859   3   100 1
chr12   88772   88859   3   100 1
chr12   89019   89674   7   100 1
chr12   89828   90586   1   100 1
chr12   90656   90795   3   100 1
chr16   101557  97558   13  100 2
chr16   103475  101646  8   100 2
chr16   104059  105458  18  100 1
chr16   105550  105776  19  100 1
chr16   105883  106538  17  100 1
chr16   106614  107085  20  100 1
chr16   108971  108759  2   100 2
chr17   84938   85187   1   100 1
chr17   88171   69528   1   100 2
chr17   93459   92763   1   100 2
chr17   96901   69528   4   100 2
chr17   100273  99697   1   100 2
chr18   107887  109384  1   100 1
```

I used on unix command line this command

sort -k 1,1 -nk2 -nk3 file.txt

It gave me:

```
chr17   84938   85187   1   100 1
chr12   86723   87265   2   100 1
chr12   87368   87556   11  100 1
chr12   87704   87880   10  100 1
chr12   88018   88256   3   75  1
chr12   88018   88569   1   25  1
chr17   88171   69528   1   100 2
chr12   88393   88569   6   100 1
chr12   88750   88859   3   100 1
chr12   88772   88859   3   100 1
chr12   89019   89674   7   100 1
chr12   89828   90586   1   100 1
chr12   90656   90795   3   100 1
chr17   93459   92763   1   100 2
chr17   96901   69528   4   100 2
chr17   100273  99697   1   100 2
chr16   101557  97558   13  100 2
chr16   103475  101646  8   100 2
chr16   104059  105458  18  100 1
chr16   105550  105776  19  100 1
chr16   105883  106538  17  100 1
chr16   106614  107085  20  100 1
chr18   107887  109384  1   100 1
chr16   108971  108759  2   100 2
```

What can i do here to get output similar to excel?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: `sort -k1,1 -k2,2n -k3,3n` ?

Comment: Can you explain me this 2n 3n part ?

Comment: `-k1,1`, `-k2,2`, and `-k3,3` specify to sort by first, second, and third column (exactly: from 1 to 1 first, from 2 to 2 second, and from 3 to 3 third).  The `n` trailing is for numeric sort.  It is the same `n` you have in the question above, but by placing it at the end of a key specification, it makes the sorting *for that key* numeric, rather than global sort.  The man/info pages are not completely clear on this; I'd need to check the source for how the options parsing is done to be confident.

Comment: See also: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/289487/117549