# Sort unix alphabetically then numerically, not working as I intended

Tags: text-processing, sort

Sorry if this is a duplicate question, but I could not find the answer that I am looking for here or in the documentation.

I have a file that looks like the following:

```
chr2_oligo1234  700 750
chr2_oligo1236  750 800
chr1_oligo1 50  100
chr1_oligo256   150 200
chr1_oligo6 3500    3550
chr4_oligo95    50  100
chr5_oligo1 50  100
chr4_oligo4 150 200
```

The desired output looks like:

```
chr1_oligo1 50  100
chr1_oligo256   150 200
chr1_oligo6 3500    3550
chr2_oligo1234  700 750
chr2_oligo1236  750 800
chr4_oligo95    50  100
chr4_oligo4 150 200
chr5_oligo1 50  100
```

The pattern at the start (e.g. chr#_oligo#) only matters in terms of the chr#, meaning that all chr1 should be first, then chr2, then chr3, etc., but I would like to sort those substrings numerically in groups as shown by the desired output above. So, I would like to know how to sort alphabetically in the case of the first column, and then keeping that order (chr1->chrN), sort each chunk of data numerically.

I apologize if my wording is not the best for this issue or if it is a duplicate. Trying

```
sort -k1,1 -nk2
```

does properly sort numerically, but does not keep the first sort intact (jumbles up the first column and places together all lines with columns 2 and 3 being like:

```
50   100
```

I am using Mac OS X.

EDIT: I want changed some of the examples in the first column to show more of what I'm looking for. gsort -V worked great if the name in the first column is in numerical order, but in my data set, it isn't always the case.

I would like to essentially sort each subgroup (in this case, chr1, chr2, etc) by column 2 iteratively. I realize this can be easily done by doing a grep for each and then sorting it on column 2, but I would like to know if sort or another unix command could accomplish this alone.

Comment: `sort -V -k1,1 -k2 file` with `gsort` (part of `coreutils`)

Comment: See http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/289487/117549

Comment: @JeffSchaller not what I was looking for. Moving the n around does not give the input I would like. Thank you though.

Comment: @don_crissti I ran "brew install coreutils" on my terminal, and had to install Xcode. This works great!  Is there a way to call gsort without typing it? I read that the sort command should be changed to call gsort instead but that does not work for me (invalid option error, meaning it is still calling the OS X sort and not coreutils version.) 

Thank you! I am changing the question a bit because it seems -V only works if the first column is in a numerical order. This is not always the case. I will change around my question.

Answer (score 6):

`sort -k1,1 -nk2` is the same as `sort -k1,1 -n -k2`, same as `sort -n -k1,1 -k2`, as in the *numerical* sorting is turned on globally, for all the keys.

To sort the 2<sup>nd</sup> key only numerically, you need to add `n` to that sort key description as in:

```
sort -k1,1 -k2n
```

Or:

```
sort -k1,1 -k2,2n
```

With `n` and with the default field separator `2` is the same as `2,2` though. `2` would be the part of the line starting from the second field, but when interpreted as a number, that's the same as the second field alone (`2,2`).

Here, you could also sort numerically on the number that is after `chr` and then alphabetically on the rest of the first field and then numerically on the second field with:

```
sort -k1.4n -k1,1 -k2n
```

Answer (score 0):

sorting alphabetically on the 1st field, and numerically on the 2nd gives (in your output, -- chr4_oligo95 is before ch4_oligo4)

```
sort -k1,1 -k2n,2n file 
chr1_oligo1 50  100
chr1_oligo256   150 200
chr1_oligo6 3500    3550
chr2_oligo1234  700 750
chr2_oligo1236  750 800
chr4_oligo4 150 200
chr4_oligo95    50  100
chr5_oligo1 50  100
```