# Ask for detail explanation on sort utility option

Tags: sort, options

I tried to use sort utility and typed sort --help, read one of lines saying its -k option, and part of it:

> OPTS is one or more single-letter ordering options [bdfgiMhnRrV], which override global ordering options for that key

I am not getting a clear understanding of the letters option usage.

Comment: Not an answer, but with GNU sort, the `--debug` option can be helpful in decipher sort's choices. [one example](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/246262/117549)

Answer (score 3):

The letters correspond to global options that influence the sort order.

For example:

```
sort -k2,2nr
```

means sort by the second column (2,2), numercially (n), in reverse order (r).